# Is there any possibility to edit a VF page that is in a managed package?

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, controller, fieldsets

we have a custom object in which we are saving customer surveys. Once the case is submitted, customer gets an email with survey link(Visual forge page) and the response will be captured in custom object. This set up was done by a outside vendor and they have installed some packages. Now, I got a requirement to make very small change in the existing survey page i.e.,.[one of the question in survey page need to be edited  from "phone" to "phone/LiveChat"].I couldn't make this change in visual force page because it is in a managed package. Is there any simple work around that  I can try  to make this happen instead of writing a new visual force page and controller.

Thank you

Comment: Answer to your question: **No**. You might try reaching out to the 'outside vendor' to see if they can get that change for you. If not, you might need to start from scratch, i.e., build from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you **cannot modify a VF page in a managed package**. Refer to the excerpt from this [**knowledge article**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220957&type=1):

> Customer has installed a managed package and this package is supported by salesforce.com support or a partner.Customer now wants to modify a VF page in this package, Can he modify ?
>
> The customer will not be able to modify the VF page.

The article discusses on options available as how you can address this scenario.